# vuetify 3 with vite does not provide an export v-tabs-slider, v-slide-items, and so on

Tags: vuetify.js, vite

I'm migrating from Vuetify 2 to Vuetify 3. I have converted all components and others specified in the migration guide of Vuetify but it doesn't work.

I have this error:

> The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vuetify_components.js?v=bd9ddd88' does not provide an export named 'VTabsSlider' (at notification.vue?t=1691499558759:1:211)

at this point:

```html
<v-tabs theme="light" v-model="activeTab">
  <v-tabs-slider color="primary"></v-tabs-slider>
  <v-tab v-for="category in xCategories" :key="`tab_${category.Cod}`">
    {{ category.Des }} ({{ category.Count }})
  </v-tab>
```

but Vuetify migration's guide doesn't specify anything about. (It seems to me)

this is my vite.config.js, I import also Vuetify3Resolver:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
// import dns from "dns";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import Components from "unplugin-vue-components/vite";
import { Vuetify3Resolver } from "unplugin-vue-components/resolvers";
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";
import monacoEditorPlugin from "vite-plugin-monaco-editor";
const prefix = `monaco-editor/esm/vs`;

// dns.setDefaultResultOrder("verbatim");
const path = require("path");
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      `${prefix}/language/json/json.worker`,
      `${prefix}/language/css/css.worker`,
      `${prefix}/language/html/html.worker`,
      `${prefix}/language/typescript/ts.worker`,
      `${prefix}/editor/editor.worker`
    ]
  },
  base: "./",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json", ".vue"],
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      "@directives": path.join(__dirname, "./src/_eng/directives"),
      "@base": path.join(__dirname, "./src/_eng/globals"),
      "@store": path.join(__dirname, "./src/_eng/store"),
      "@main": path.join(__dirname, "./src/_eng/main"),
      "@adm": path.join(__dirname, "./src/app/adm"),
      "@test": path.join(__dirname, "./src/test"),
      "@custom": path.join(__dirname, "./src/custom/erp"),
      "@assets": path.join(__dirname, "./assets"),
      "@c_assets": path.join(__dirname, "./src/custom/erp", "/assets"),
      "@erpcomp": path.join(__dirname, "./src/_eng/erpcomp"),
      "devextreme/ui": "devextreme/esm/ui",
      vue: "@vue/compat"
    }
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      treeshake: false
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    host: "localhost",
    proxy: {
      "^/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:5000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true,
        secure: false,
        configure: (proxy, _options) => {
          proxy.on("error", (err, _req, _res) => {
            console.error("proxy error", err);
          });
          // proxy.on("proxyReq", (proxyReq, req, _res) => {
          //   console.log("Sending Request to the Target:", req.method, req.url);
          // });
          // proxy.on("proxyRes", (proxyRes, req, _res) => {
          //   console.log("Received Response from the Target:", proxyRes.statusCode, req.url);
          // });
        },
        rewrite: path => {
          const x = path.replace("/api", "");
          return x;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  preview: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080
  },
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          compatConfig: {
            MODE: 2
          }
        }
      }
    }),
    VitePWA(),
    monacoEditorPlugin({ languages: ["javascript"] }),
    vuetify(),
    Components({
      resolvers: [Vuetify3Resolver()]
    })
  ],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: [
          // Make the variables defined in these files available to all components, without requiring an explicit
          // @import of the files themselves
          '@import "./src/scss/variables.scss";',
          '@import "vuetify/settings.scss";',
          "" // end with newline
        ].join("\n")
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Please, could anyone help me?

Comment: The migration guide is not comprehensive.  Check the rest of the Vuetify 3 documentation for `VTabsSlider` component.  You'll find it doesn't exist anymore, which is why you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a property of `<v-tabs ... />`, `slider-color`, that sets the background colour for an automatically-generated `<v-tabs-slider ... />`. I think your update looks like:

```html
<v-tabs theme="light" v-model="activeTab" slider-color="primary">
  <!-- <v-tabs-slider color="primary"></v-tabs-slider> -->
  <v-tab v-for="category in xCategories" :key="`tab_${category.Cod}`">
    {{ category.Des }} ({{ category.Count }})
  </v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

See also:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tabs/#props-slider-color

Answer (score 0):

In Vuetify 3, the v-tabs-slider component has been replaced with the VTabsItems component. To resolve this issue, you need to update your code to use the new component.

Here's how you can update your template code:

```
<v-tabs theme="light" v-model="activeTab">
    <v-tabs-items>
        <v-tabs-item v-for="category in xCategories" :key="`tab_${category.Cod}`">
        {{ category.Des }} ({{ category.Count }})
        </v-tabs-item>
    </v-tabs-items>
</v-tabs>
```

Comment: v-tabs-item(s) give me the same error: "The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vuetify_components.js?v=6b20b16f' does not provide an export named 'VTabsItems'"